# How to get sensors-detect to detect an AMD Phenom II temtperature sensor

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, amd, sensors

Yes, I know that is an old chip.

Running a `sensors-detect` with all the optional tests yields nothing. My `sensors` refuse to read the temperature of the CPU. I know there is a working temperature sensor in there because I can see the correct temperature in the BIOS.

Does anyone know which kernel module I have to enable? Or how to find out without `sensors-detect`?

My CPU is a 6 core AMD Phenom II 1090T.

Just in case, here is the complete output of `lsmod`. `sensors-detect` loaded `k10temp`, which does not detect the CPU temperature.

```
Module                  Size  Used by
binfmt_misc            24576  1
dm_multipath           32768  0
scsi_dh_rdac           16384  0
scsi_dh_emc            16384  0
scsi_dh_alua           20480  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  4
snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
joydev                 24576  0
input_leds             16384  0
ccp                    86016  0
snd_timer              36864  1 snd_pcm
snd                    90112  8 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm
kvm                   663552  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
k10temp                16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
nct6775                69632  0
hwmon_vid              16384  1 nct6775
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
btrfs                1261568  0
zstd_compress         167936  1 btrfs
raid10                 57344  0
raid456               155648  0
async_raid6_recov      24576  1 raid456
async_memcpy           20480  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_pq               24576  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_xor              20480  3 async_pq,raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_tx               20480  5 async_pq,async_memcpy,async_xor,raid456,async_raid6_recov
xor                    24576  2 async_xor,btrfs
raid6_pq              114688  4 async_pq,btrfs,raid456,async_raid6_recov
libcrc32c              16384  2 btrfs,raid456
raid1                  45056  0
raid0                  24576  0
multipath              20480  0
linear                 20480  0
nouveau              1949696  1
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    32768  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  49152  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
ttm                   106496  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 nouveau
pata_acpi              16384  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
hid_generic            16384  0
uas                    28672  1
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  90112  0
usbhid                 57344  0
realtek                24576  1
pata_atiixp            16384  2
usb_storage            77824  1 uas
drm                   491520  4 drm_kms_helper,ttm,nouveau
i2c_piix4              28672  0
hid                   131072  2 usbhid,hid_generic
ahci                   40960  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
```

For good measure, I also present the current output of `sensors`:

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +36.5°C  (high = +70.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:    900.00 mV (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.05 V)
temp1:        +52.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

nct6776-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:           1.20 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:           192.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
AVCC:            3.30 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+3.3V:           3.28 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in4:           528.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:             1.67 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:             1.83 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
3VSB:            3.44 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
Vbat:            3.39 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.63 V)
fan1:           865 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:          3890 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:             0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:             0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:             0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:         +40.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:         +45.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN:         -26.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:   +0.0°C  
PCH_CPU_TEMP:    +0.0°C  
PCH_MCH_TEMP:    +0.0°C  
intrusion0:    OK
intrusion1:    OK
beep_enable:   disabled
```

The nouveau entry is of course a graphics card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`k10temp`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/hwmon/k10temp.html) is the CPU temperature sensor. With older AMD CPUs you get only one value, which isn't even "real" temperature:

> For CPUs older than Family 17h, there is one temperature measurement
> value, available as temp1_input in sysfs. It is measured in degrees
> Celsius with a resolution of 1/8th degree. Please note that it is
> defined as a relative value; to quote the AMD manual:
>
> > Tctl is the processor temperature control value, used by the platform
> > to control cooling systems. Tctl is a non-physical temperature on an
> > arbitrary scale measured in degrees. It does *not* represent an actual
> > physical temperature like die or case temperature. Instead, it
> > specifies the processor temperature relative to the point at which the
> > system must supply the maximum cooling for the processor's specified
> > maximum case temperature and maximum thermal power dissipation.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! Followup question: The man page states that this value is available as "temp1_input", but my "temp1_input" maps to "SYSTIN", while "CPUTIN" has the value of "temp2_input" (according to `sensors -u`). Which one is correct? Bear in mind that I know absolutely nothing about sensors.